# defaultdict constant_factory doesn't behave as expected

Tags: python, factory, defaultdict

I'm willing to use `defaultdict` with an *ad hoc* `default_factory` which suits better my purpose. The `default_factory` would be `[0,0]`.

I've implemented a `constant_factory` function:

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return itertools.repeat(value).next
```

Then when I try to use it, my `defaultdict` has an unexpected behavior (at least a behavior I didn't expect).

Here is an example:

```
>>>import itertools
>>>from collections import defaultdict
>>>dictio=defaultdict(constant_factory([0,0]))
>>>for i in xrange(10):
...    dictio[i][0]+=1
>>>dictio
defaultdict(<method-wrapper 'next' of itertools.repeat object at 0x000000000355FC50>, {0: [10, 0], 1: [10, 0], 2: [10, 0], 3: [10, 0], 4: [10, 0], 5: [10, 0], 6: [10, 0], 7: [10, 0], 8: [10, 0], 9: [10, 0]})
```

Instead I'd like to get: `defaultdict(<method-wrapper 'next' of itertools.repeat object at 0x000000000355FC50>, {0: [1, 0], 1: [1, 0], 2: [1, 0], 3: [1, 0], 4: [1, 0], 5: [1, 0], 6: [1, 0], 7: [1, 0], 8: [1, 0], 9: [1, 0]})`

It seems that, each time I'm willing to increment the value of the first slot of the list corresponding to the key `i`, it increments all the values of the the first slots.

Since I'm pretty new to using defaultdict and method wrapper can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong since I believe Python is doing its work perfectly well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, just use:

```
defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
```

Your rather elaborate callable returns *the same list* over and over again. You are using the same list for **all** values in your dictionary. The above lambda returns a *new* list each time it is called instead:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lambda_default = lambda: [0, 0]
>>> iter_default = itertools.repeat([0, 0]).next
>>> lambda_default() is lambda_default()
False
>>> iter_default() is iter_default()
True
```

You thus fill your dictionary with references to *one* list, and altering values in that one list is reflected everywhere the reference to that one list is printed.

Comment: Thank you everything is clear ! I read the documentation and found the constant_factory method but I used it without understanding how it worked.