# How is Python itertools `constant_factory` example superior to `lambda : x`?

Tags: python, lambda, python-itertools

In the documentation of `defaultdict` there is this example:

```
>>> def constant_factory(value):
...     return itertools.repeat(value).next
```

as a "A faster and more flexible way to create constant functions".

How is this superior to

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return lambda : value
```

?

Note that of course no one would define a function for that... just using `(lambda: 42)` is clearer and shorter to type than calling `constant_factory(42)`.

For creating a constant factory returning a mutable if that is wanted one could use `(lambda x=[]:x)` (btw this is what would do `constant_factory([])`, but it's something that often bites back ... see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18108775/320726)).

Comment: Maybe the itertools implementation is optimized and faster than a general lambda?

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly enough using `itertools.repeat(value).next` is actually about <strike>30%</strike> **two-three times faster** in both Python 2 and Python 3 (with the obvious variation of `__next__`).

<strike>It's not much but also</strike> there's no reason to waste it.

<strike>PS: I'd say this shows that `lambda` could be improved (I see no logical reason for having a bound method faster than a closure) but `lambda` is not really loved in the Python community.</strike>

The reason for this is that `itertools` primitives are implemented in C while a lambda executes Python bytecode. Just returning a captured value is really fast, but however it's still bytecode and requires a lot of setup/teardown like any Python function call.

Comment: It's not that `lambda` is slower than `itertools.repeat`, it's that Python functions are slower than C functions. If you check the bytecode and the functions' types, you'll see that the `lambda` is precisely equivalent to `def <lambda>(): return value`. The fact that `value` is a closure variable may come into play as well, but a hard-coded `lamda: 42` already takes 1.77x as long as `repeat` in my measurements.